# HIVEMQ-KAFKA extension

Tags: apache-kafka, hivemq

I copied the folder of HIVEMQ-KAFKA extension to the HIVEMQ extension folder but it is giving me this error:

```
WARN  - Extension hivemq-kafka-extension cannot be loaded. The extension signature could not be read. The signature of an enterprise extension is required by HiveMQ. Reason: zip END header not found
```

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO SHOUT :)

Comment: I HAVE REMOVED MOST OF THE THE SHOUTING

Comment: Well played … 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> zip END header not found

This usually means that the file is corrupted. Try re-downloading it, and check it against the checksums if provided.

Comment: Yes, it's working..Thanksss where as I also copied the licence folder entities from extension to the license folder.

Comment: Do you know where to find the cluster-id in kafka? As I need to pass the cluster id in hivemq extension but only id i know is broker.id which is in meta.properties but it's not working.

Comment: You can set the cluster-id in the kafka extension config. Any String will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your ZIP / jar seems to be corrupt.
The other other question: Yes, the Kafka Extension is an Enterprise extension. For those you need additional a license to run it in production. But in development environment you can try out, cause you have an evaluation time of 5 hours. After this time,  the extension will be disabled and to re/enable you must remove the DISABLED flag in the kafka-extension folder. More information you can find on the HiveMQ Developer and Configuration Pages.